# How can I simplify code in the body by working through the head?

Tags: html, css, alias, head, simplify

New to this, bare with me please.

I've started having fun with HTML code doing offline documents.  I just found out that I could easily change my font, in the head, by adding this:

```
<style type=text/css>
    mkf { font-family:'Courier'; color:red; }
</style>
```

Then, as I go to add code to , every time I want to change the font of a select group of word with the addition of the color red, I just need to type

```
<mkf>words here</mkf>
```

Wonderful!  It saves me so much time.  But then I got to wonder, what if I wanted to add a link to a word.  For example, instead of typing all of this out:

```
<a href="to_do_list.pdf"><mkf>Example1</mkf></a>
```

I would simply be able to parse whatever text I inputted between, let's say,

```
<linkandfont>Example1</linkandfont>,
```

which would basically create a link to the file "to_do_list.pdf".

I've tried to find a name or term for this so that I can study and learn more, but I have not found it yet.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not possible only using html, this can be done using javascript. You need to start learning javascript now.

Comment: shotgun02 what general area would I look under to do what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Only way to create a link in HTML is by typing `<a href="URL">description</a>`. You could also shorten by using JavaScript but that's not HTML.

The way you changed the color in head is part of styling or CSS, so you could give a `class` to `a` tag like `<a class='redlink' href='..` and define that class in head like you did with mkf : `.redlink {color:red}` or if you want all your links to be red then you could give color to `a` in head style: `a {color:red;}`

By typing <mkf> in body I guess you created custom tag which is not part of standard HTML tags, more proper way would be using `class` to a standard tag like `div` or `p`.

Comment: That's a bummer.  From the reading that I've done, creating things in CSS is suppose to be a real time saver.  Writing out 'a href' a million times instead of being able to use an alias makes it more difficult to do, more difficult to read and more prone to errors.

Comment: You are right, to shorten traditional boilerplate codes people have invented frameworks and libraries like Angular, React, Vue etc. If you are planning to become frontend developer those would be next steps after JavaScript. For now you can only stick to traditional ways. But your curiosity to make things easier is admirable!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using classes instead? These achieve the same thing. For example;

```
<style>
    .mkf {
        font-family:'Courier';
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="mkf">test</div>
```

However, to properly answer your question, what you want is ABSOLUTELY possible in HTML5 and CSS3. And I've used such methods in certain projects of mine (just know this isn't entirely Kocher or conventional).

```css
mkf {
    font-family:'Courier';
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<mkf>this is working</mkf>
```

As for making `<linkToSomething>Click Here</linkToSomething>` not as easy. You would definitely need JavaScript etc to handle all that. You won't achieve it in CSS and HTML alone.

Comment: I'd love to see how you achieved it.  Can you point me in the direction to do this?

Comment: Achieved what? To which part of my answer are you referring?

Comment: "what you want is ABSOLUTELY possible in HTML5 and CSS3. And I've used such methods in certain projects of mine (just know this isn't entirely Kocher or conventional)."  I'd love to see how you achieved it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Sorry, I missed the bottom part.  I get what you're saying with making classes, but it just makes it so much more difficult to read when I can do <>.  I've only been doing this for less than a month but have done other programming in my past.  I've always tried to code things so that they're easier to find errors.  HTML is incredibly difficult to catch errors when you have to constantly type out long phrases like a href.

Guess I'll have to jump into Java.  What I'm doing isn't that complicated though, so it'll be some time for me to do that. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Haha yeah I know what you mean. You'll get used to it, or find a decent editor like VSCode or Notepad++ with a nice theme and the code can start looking pretty nice with all the colours etc haha. Also don't confuse Java for JavaScript :)

Comment: Thanks for the Java/JavaScript tip...I had no idea they were different!  I'll have to look for a good editor, right now I'm using apple's textedit, and all lettering is white on a black background.

Comment: Yeah, definitely gross. Look in to Notepad++ or VSCode (both are free). Haha and yeah, careful with the Java/JavaScript thing - some people can be quite anal about the difference where others may just shrug it off. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: Actually, you are Mac, so Notepad++ won't be an option - you could look into VSCode or Sublime Text. They will make your code a little pretty and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded VSCode...and how refreshing it is to have color!  Thank you for your input.  Very much appreciated.